# How to Convert Rtp Multicast Stream from DVB-T to HLS?

Tags: multicast, rtp, http-live-streaming, dvb-t

I use Mumudvb to get signal from dvb-t and dvb-s to RTP Multicast stream and successfully do that, The result stream URL is something like rtp://239.1.2.1:60001.

Now i want to know How can i convert RTP (Or UDP)stream to Http Live Stream (HLS)?

**Edit**:

I could convert live stream with ffmpeg, but its not stable, when an error occurred in ffmpeg the conversation stop and there is no way to found fail and for example restart ffmpeg, I am looking for new way for that convert operation.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC can probably do this, something along the lines of:

```
cvlc -vvv rtp://@239.1.2.1:60001
--sout '#std{access=livehttp{seglen=5,delsegs=true,numsegs=5,
index=/path/to/stream.m3u8,
index-url=http://example.org/stream-########.ts},
mux=ts{use-key-frames},
dst=/path/to/stream-########.ts}'
```

Substitute `/path/to/stream*` with whatever path you want to serve your playlist and segments from, and `http://example.org` with your machine's domain name or IP address.

See these [command line examples](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/) for further pointers.

I'm not sure if VLC retries more gracefully after input errors than ffmpeg. In any case, you can script retry after failure behavior, [here is one example](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/restart-encoding-with-ffmpeg-when-bad-source).