# Viewing a live Multicast RTP stream with HTML5

Tags: streaming, iptv

I’ve searched and read all the posts I can find, but I don’t think I get it. We have an extron SMP that provides us with a multicast live RTP stream. This stream can be viewed from any computer on our network using VLC Player. Now we want to play this stream in our browser.

I know that you cannot natively play the stream and must convert it real time to an HTML compatible version. This is where I am having issues.

I have attempted to use the program ‘udpxy’ which converted the multicast stream to an H264 HTTP Stream, but I could never find an HTML player that would play the stream. It worked in VLC, But the ‘video’ tag, videoJS, not jwplayer would work.

I also attempted to use nginx and the nginx rtmp module and failed miserably. Could never get nginx to serve a stream.

Could some elaborate on the method that I need to use to convert the multicast RTP stream to an HTML5 compliant stream.

Comment: The may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41504905/334402

Answer (score 0):

**HTML5 Video** does not support RTP streaming, so feed into streaming server(NMS) like FLV for flvjs, or forward to h264 rtsp proxy(Simple RTSP Server) for WebRTC streamer.

`Node Media Server` and `SRS` projects are avaliable in github. both work second latency performance in standard HTML5 Video validated.

Answer (score 0):

You may find interesting to have a look at http://live555.com/hlsProxy/ which converts an RTSP/RTP stream to HLS and your web browser client might be able to play it natively. There is also a Javascript library https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/ that can help.

However don't expect to have a very low latency with HLS.